# How to use an operator from a specific base class on multiple inheritance context on C++

Tags: c++, operators, virtual, multiple-inheritance

I'm writing some C++ codes, and I can't compile the following code on g++. It only says that std::string hasn't a method named "operator==". I know it's not truth, but perhaps there is some multiple inheritance restrictions or problems I don't know yet.

The code:

```cpp
#include<string>

struct Object{

    constexpr Object() noexcept = default;
    virtual ~Object() noexcept = default;

    virtual bool operator==( const Object& other) const noexcept = 0;
};


class String : public Object, public std::string{

    virtual ~String() noexcept = default;
    String() noexcept = default;

    virtual bool operator==( const Object& other) const noexcept{

        auto ptr =  dynamic_cast<const String*>(&other);

        return ptr != nullptr &&
            this->std::string::operator==(*ptr);    // here is the error
    }
};

int main(){}
```

The error:

$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test.run

> test.cpp: In member function ‘virtual bool String::operator==(const Object&) const’:
> test.cpp:23:31: error: ‘class std::__cxx11::basic_string’ has no member named ‘operator==’; did you mean ‘operator=’?
> this->std::string::operator==(*ptr);

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have the operator as a member, it is a global operator.

```
((std::string&)*this) == (*ptr);
```

See non-member functions section in the docs: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Comment: Truth! I've not realise the 'Non-member functions' title on the reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string . Thank you.